# What precisely causes "You need to format the disk in drive X:"?

Tags: hard-drive, check-disk

I get this message on an XP machine and the drive is an internal hard disk.

I checkdisked, got a few file clusters fixed and the problem seems to be gone.

Can a problem local to a few clusters generate such a "far reaching" message, causing the loss of all data if you blindly follow the advice ?

Has anyone insight on the circumstances that cause this message ? And should I worry about the reliability of this disk in the future ?

Comment: if the disks filesystem metadata cannot be loaded the system will assume no filesystem is present. There are hidden data structures at the beginning of the disk that indicate what type of file system is present, and how to read it to get files and directory structures. without this information you don't really have a file system. It sounds like your bad blocks intersected with the disks metadata, and until they were replaced, the system could not find a valid filesystem existed. As for the disks longevity and health, check its SMART stats. bad blocks tend to increase exponentially to time.

Comment: @FrankThomas: thanks, this is instructive. You can turn the comment in an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a problem local to a few clusters generate such a "far reaching" message, causing the loss of all data if you blindly follow the advice ?

Yes.

All this message indicates is that Windows did not find a mountable volume.  (Sometimes volumes are called "filesystems", and they are located inside "partitions".)

If information that defines the partition's boundaries and/or "Type" ID is wrong, you can get this message.  If the information on the volume's header is wrong, you can get this message.

> Has anyone insight on the circumstances that cause this message ?

For removable media, sometimes this message has been known to show up temporarily: removing the media and re-inserting caused the media to work just fine.

If you have precious data, make sure to back up that data.  (Make an image of the entire volume, if needed.  You'll need some other accessible disk space to write to, in order to do that.)

> And should I worry about the reliability of this disk in the future ?

The error message you provided isn't real common.  This can result from things like a power outage, or even a software glitch (BSOD), which results in the operating system not shutting down properly.  If the problem is caused by software (e.g., bad driver) or data (e.g., incorrect file table), then the problem might be entirely fixable by software (e.g., chkdsk, re-format), and the hardware may continue to serve just fine.

On the other hand, it could be hardware.

Hardware testing might reveal some types of problems.  Sometimes hardware can self-diagnose certain problems, so S.M.A.R.T. may be able to reveal that.  Sometimes stressing out hardware can reveal problems that, if left unchecked, are likely to spread over time (and cause even bigger problems), so running some "hardware testing" software may be worthwhile.  Sometimes problems exist that aren't detected by such techniques, so nothing is 100% certain.  If problems do exist, they may be with the hard drive, with data cabling, or even unrelated components like RAM.

If you're worried about the hardware, the absolute best thing you can do is to get a backup onto different hardware.  Then, check S.M.A.R.T. and see if any other hardware testing reveals problems.  If not, then use the hardware as confidently as you would with other hardware.  (Since it is true that things do fail, these days I tend not to feel 100% confident about any specific computer.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. From the checkdisk report, I didn't get the feeling that system blocks were damaged, just ordinary files, and a first peek at the SMART info didn't reveal a severe condition (though I must admit I will need to dive deeper to understand all). In the short term, I will make sure that backups are frequent and wait to see if the problem pops up again.